# Do electron's spins change the position of other electrons like in Stern Gerlach experiment?

Tags: quantum-spin

In [electron B strength](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/739930/how-strong-is-the-magnetic-field-due-to-the-electrons-spin/739934#739934) he said that at 1 nm distance B is 1 miliTesla. So, is this strong enough to affect the motion of other electrons?. Will change their trajectories and kinetic energy too?. Will this happen in human body?